# How to wrap text around left floating image in wordpress

Tags: html, css, image, wordpress, css-float

If you visit http://www.timkainu.com/journal/ you can see that there are some "featured images" floating to the left of the text.  How can the text wrap around the image?  I've used Firebug to try and find out what part of the CSS affects it, but I failed, obviously.

The site runs on WordPress and the theme being used is called "Striking", which is found on ThemeForest.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You are going to have to make some change to the theme to make that work. In order for text to wrap around an image, the text and image need to be in the same container. In this case, the image is in one DIV and the text is in the DIV next to it. You'd need to move div.image_styled.entry_image inside of div.entry_info to make it work. You would probably need to make some CSS adjustments as well since it was not design to wrap around the images like that.

Answer (score 0):

Are you referring to, for example, the first item "Costco Photo Center Review" with the image of Costco on the left?

The image is wrapped inside `<div class="image_styled entry_image"></div>`
and the text is wrapped inside `<div class="entry_info"></div>`, both of which are wrapped inside `<article id="xxx" class="entry entry_left">`

In order for text to wrap around the image, they need to be in the same container, with the image set to `float: left`. I'm not sure how this relates to Wordpress, but in terms of HTML and CSS, that's the way to go.